# why does this output hex rather than a sentence? connector/c++

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector, istream, connector

I was expecting to see a short english sentence as output but i see hex value of it instread. I cannot find any information on this getblob function but i hear its what should be used for varchar columns. Before i used getString and it crashes the app, its funny though becuase it crashes after it successfully prints the sentence sometimes. However i cant have it crashing so i need to make it work with getblob, it returns an std::istream which i no nothing about. I experimented with converting istream to string but my lack of understanding of what an isteam is did not get me far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

#include "cppconn\driver.h"
#include "cppconn\connection.h"
#include "cppconn\statement.h"
#include "cppconn\prepared_statement.h"
#include "cppconn\resultset.h"
#include "cppconn\metadata.h"
#include "cppconn\resultset_metadata.h"
#include "cppconn\exception.h"
#include "cppconn\warning.h"
#include "cppconn\datatype.h"   
#include "cppconn\parameter_metadata.h"
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include "mysql_driver.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;
    sql::Statement *stmt;

    // ...
    driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
    cout<<"Connecting to database...\n";
con = driver->connect("tcp://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306", "xxxxx", "xxxxxx");


sql::ResultSet *res;
// ...
stmt = con->createStatement();
// ...
 con->setSchema("mrhowtos_main");
res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT english FROM `eng` WHERE `ID` = 16;");
while (res->next()) {
      istream *stream = res->getBlob(1);

      string s; 
    getline(*stream, s); //crashes here - access violation
    cout << s << endl; 
}
cout<<"done\n";
delete res;
delete stmt;
delete con;
system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: crashes on getline

value of stream after getblob:

- stream  0x005f3e88 {_Chcount=26806164129143632 }    std::basic_istream > *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This answered the first version of this question, which had a `cout << stream << endl;` statement.)

---

You're printing an `istream *`.

I suppose you would like to read from that `istream` and print what you read, e.g. with

```
string s; 
while (getline(*stream, s))
  cout << s << endl;
```

Comment: I replaced my cout line with your code. it crashes with access violation on the line with getline. I suppose its because s was not initialized maybe.

Comment: No, that should be OK.  Are you sure the rest of your code works as expected?  E.g. that `res->getBlob(1)` returns indeed a stream that produces your query's result?

Comment: Should you be closing the stream between successive iterations of your `while` loop?  Try `delete stream;`.

Comment: the value of stream after the getblob seems like it did not fail. here is what it says in the watch variable:
    +  stream 0x00ab3e88 {_Chcount=48198262359153488 } std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char> > *

Comment: even if i remove the while loop and just use the getline once, it crashes on the call to getline

Comment: Well, this code works: `istream *stream = new ifstream("a.txt"); string s; while (getline(*stream, s)) cout << s << endl;`

Comment: Does it crash the first time you reach getline (first iteration of `while (res->next())`?  If not, did you try `delete stream;` after the `cout`?

Comment: if you see my code update above, i tried remove the while loop and just calling getline once, it crashes on the getline with access violation. before the cout.

Comment: Yes I saw it.  What I'm asking is, does this happen in the first iteration of `while (res->next())`?  You still have that.

Comment: oh sorry, yes it happens on the first iteration. I tried o replace my getblob line with your istream *stream = new ifstream("a.txt"); just to see if that would prevent the crash but i get a linker error when i do that -.- ....

Comment: You'll need an `#include <fstream>` for that.  And a file `a.txt`, of course.

Comment: yes i did include fstream and made a real file, its a linker error not compiler error.

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure this out.  Without something I can run, I'm not much help.